# TypeScript: TsLib doesn't contain __importStar (__importStar is not a function)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm having real trouble with a TypeScript react project that's been working fine, then half way through the day broke.

I'm getting `TypeError: tslib_1.__importStar is not a function` when importing a particular dependency.

I've been into the dependency and it has:

```
var tslib_1 = require("tslib");
var url = tslib_1.__importStar(require("url"));
```

In the dependency project, I can go to the tslib and it has that function:

```
export declare function __extends(d: Function, b: Function): void;
export declare function __assign(t: any, ...sources: any[]): any;
export declare function __rest(t: any, propertyNames: (string | symbol)[]): any;
export declare function __decorate(decorators: Function[], target: any, key?: string | symbol, desc?: any): any;
export declare function __param(paramIndex: number, decorator: Function): Function;
export declare function __metadata(metadataKey: any, metadataValue: any): Function;
export declare function __awaiter(thisArg: any, _arguments: any, P: Function, generator: Function): any;
export declare function __generator(thisArg: any, body: Function): any;
export declare function __exportStar(m: any, exports: any): void;
export declare function __values(o: any): any;
export declare function __read(o: any, n?: number): any[];
export declare function __spread(...args: any[]): any[];
export declare function __await(v: any): any;
export declare function __asyncGenerator(thisArg: any, _arguments: any, generator: Function): any;
export declare function __asyncDelegator(o: any): any;
export declare function __asyncValues(o: any): any;
export declare function __makeTemplateObject(cooked: string[], raw: string[]): TemplateStringsArray;
export declare function __importStar<T>(mod: T): T;
export declare function __importDefault<T>(mod: T): T | { default: T };
```

However, if I follow the dependency in the React project I'm importing it in (ctrl-clicking on the `import("tslib")` from the node modules file, I get:

```
export declare function __extends(d: Function, b: Function): void;
export declare function __assign(t: any, ...sources: any[]): any;
export declare function __rest(t: any, propertyNames: (string | symbol)[]): any;
export declare function __decorate(decorators: Function[], target: any, key?: string | symbol, desc?: any): any;
export declare function __param(paramIndex: number, decorator: Function): Function;
export declare function __metadata(metadataKey: any, metadataValue: any): Function;
export declare function __awaiter(thisArg: any, _arguments: any, P: Function, generator: Function): any;
export declare function __generator(thisArg: any, body: Function): any;
export declare function __exportStar(m: any, exports: any): void;
export declare function __values(o: any): any;
export declare function __read(o: any, n?: number): any[];
export declare function __spread(...args: any[]): any[];
export declare function __await(v: any): any;
export declare function __asyncGenerator(thisArg: any, _arguments: any, generator: Function): any;
export declare function __asyncDelegator(o: any): any;
export declare function __asyncValues(o: any): any;
```

`importStar` is indeed missing. But why? I've tried various compiler options:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDirs": ["src", "__component_tests__"],
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

(Not sure how the compiler options updates the node_modules tslib dependency though?

Reverted the branch back to an earlier commit and it's fixed - even though looking at the diff I can see no change that could have caused such symptoms...

Comment: For others finding this via Google like me, note that `__importStar` and `__importDefault` were [added](https://github.com/microsoft/tslib/commit/b630cee42bd40250d5f1ce65fd697c2f2fc86fbf) in release [1.9.0](https://github.com/microsoft/tslib/releases/tag/1.9.0) of tslib, so check your version if your code can't find them (`npm list | grep tslib`).

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla I can't remember! I think manually installing a later version of tslib solved the problem.